# How to set hidden fields in redux form in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-redux-form

How to set hidden fields in redux form in react native ?

i jsut cannot find any way on how to do that . any help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

i ended using this :

```
this.props.dispatch(change("FORM_NAME","FIELD_NAME","VALUE"))
```

after this code runs, the form will create the field if it does not exists

Comment: This way you cant fire validations as there is no Redux form -Field listening to the value.

Comment: You need to import [`change`](https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/docs/api/actioncreators.md/#-change-form-string-field-string-value-string-) (a Redux Form action creator) like this: `import { change } from 'redux-form'` for this.

Comment: `this.props.change('FIELD_NAME', 'VALUE')` is the injected version which is recommended according to the [documentation](https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/docs/api/actioncreators.md/): it is recommended that you use the actions passed as props to your component for most of your needs, as they are already bound to `dispatch`.

Comment: Thank you @Roy CL I've been searching this thing.a long ago.

Answer (score 5):

I have faced the same issue.
What I do is to declare a Field like this and set the height to 0.
It is a little bit hacky but it works in my case.

```
<Field
    component={TextInput}
    name="departure_city_name"
    type="hidden"
    style={{ height: 0 }}
/>
```

And I change the value like this : `this.props.change("departure_city_name", cityData.name);`

Hope it helps.

Comment: i found that u do not need the field even. just dispatch the value for the field

Comment: Oh yess. Cool. I've just tested it :) . Thanks

Answer (score 5):

you don't need to dispatch any action just perform this change whenever you need a hidden field in redux form.

```
this.props.change('Field_name', value)
```

Comment: Yes, Because now things have been changed, so if someone is using it in latest version(Because not sure where they updated it but Version 8 i am using), we just need to use the change prop to set the value for the fields.

Answer (score 2):

Technically you don't need to create a type=hidden field because you can call the `change` function for the 'hidden' field you want to change if the field doesn't exist Redux-form will add it to your form state like an actual field

```
MyForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'myForm'
})(MyForm)

MyForm = connect(
  state => ({
    initialValues: { areYouOk: 'no' }
  })
)(MyForm)

export default MyForm
```

Whether you've set up initial values or not you'll always be able to call the change function with your new hidden value and it'll work anyway

```
  let MyForm = ({ submitHandler, change }) => {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <button
         onClick={() => {
           change('areYouOk', 'yes');
         }}
         label={'Yes'}
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
```