# Get TextInput value from state Redux Form on react native

Tags: react-native, redux, field, redux-form

I have a code with diferents Fields. When from other component pass the new values I have four fields with this values that I generate her value with this.state.

But when I do handleSubmit() this Inputs not send. I have done a test change her value once I have already loaded them and now yes they are sent.

How do I receive these values in the handlesubmit?

This is a part of code:

```
    changeImage = (values) => {

        if (values.type == "profile")
            this.setState({changePersonalImage: true});
         else if (values.type == "featured")
            this.setState({changeFeaturedImage: true});
         else if (values.type == "project")
            this.setState({changeProjectImage: true});


        this.setState(values);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>  
                <View>
                    {this.state.changePersonalImage &&
                        <View>
                            <Field name="personalImage_type" component={genericField} type="hidden" val={this.state.profile_type} />
                            <Field name="personalImage_fileName" component={genericField} type="hidden" val={this.state.profile_fileName} />
                            <Field name="personalImage_image" component={genericField} type="hidden" val={this.state.profile_image} />
                            <Field name="personalImage_isVertical" component={genericField} type="hidden" val={this.state.profile_isVertical} />
                        </View>
                    }

                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={styles.btnRequest}
                        //onPress={this.props.handleSubmit(this.props.edit)}
                        onPress={this.props.handleSubmit((values) => {
                            console.log('valuess - handleSubmit');
                            console.log(values);
                        })}
                    >
                        <WhiteText style={styles.btnRequestText}>Save changes</WhiteText>                   
                    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved,

I found a solution in this post [How to set hidden fields in redux form in react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44218104/how-to-set-hidden-fields-in-redux-form-in-react-native)

The problem is create a hidden fields. The solution is call this method:

`this.props.change('Field_name', value)`